# jQuery .delay() not working in Chrome, but fine in IE

Tags: jquery, delay

I was making some stuff and afterwards I noticed the delay function was working fine in IE, but doesn't do anything in Chrome and I really don't know why. It is really basic stuff. So before I start changing everything to setTimeout functions I would like to ask for advice.

Many thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#start").width(0);
    $("#start").delay(1000).animate({
        width: '280px'
    }, 750);

    $("#info").delay(2500).fadeIn(5000);

    $("#in").delay(1250).fadeIn(1000);
    $("#plusmin").fadeIn(2000);

    $('#arrow').delay(2000).fadeIn(4000);
});​
```

Comment: What version of jquery ? jsFiddle ?

Comment: Working in Chrome... http://jsfiddle.net/bZezzz/W29Yr/

Comment: As mentioned below, setTimeout() would be a good alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xwVF6/

Works fine in my Chrome V23.

Make sure you don't have multiple of the same ID's, and are using a newer jquery version (newer that 1.3 which is when delay was added).

Else please provide some HTML ;-)

`SetTimeout()` might be better if you are making dependent animations (show A, then show B 0.5 seconds after A etc).

Comment: Ok thanks. I see it works, but mine still does not. So there must be something else to it...

So here is the actual page I'm working on: http://vangils.imaxxserver.be/

Comment: You using fancybox, but the script is not included, so it throws an error. Ill try to debug the delay ;-)

Comment: Not yet, will be added in later pages.

Comment: @user1844439 the reason "delay" is not working, is because your inline styling shows the box, so it wont fadein, when its already got opacity set to 1 and display set to block. Try removing your inline styling, and it works ;-)

Comment: Just remember that when javascript throws an error, it will stop that function, so it might give you headaches. So you should either outcomment it or include the library ;-)

Comment: Hmm, I removed the inline styling, but that still doesn't do the trick. What I did find is that when I remove this line:

<script src="js/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>

it works fine. But it is needed for the background slides, however I don't really know what is does...

Comment: OH I got it now! Removed the inline style AND the "jquery.animate-enhanced" and now it works. Looked like a combination of the two.

Thank you so much for getting me back on track!!!

Really appreciate you took some time to help me!

Comment: @user1844439 remember to accept the anwser, if your problem is solved ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Created a sample . And its working fine in Chrome

```
#start {background-color:#000;height:100px;}
#info {background-color:red;height:100px;display:none}
#in {background-color:green;height:100px;display:none}
#plusmin {background-color:yellow;height:100px;display:none}
#arrow {background-color:blue;height:100px;display:none}​
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/W29Yr/3/)